# Reading a nested WPF XAML control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a XAML control which I can't access in the code behind and I was wondering why and how to resolve this.

I'm trying to access the *uxQuanity* control in *ProductSearchControl.cs*.

In *ProductSearchControl.cs*, I can access

```
this.productListControl.uxProducts.SelectedItem
```

but I've tried the following to access *uxQuantity* and they don't work:

```
this.productListControl.uxQuantity
this.productListControl.DataGridColumnQuantity.uxQuantity
```

code: (I've edited out code that I think is irrelevant)

**Controls.ProductSearchControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Controls.ProductSearchControl">
<DockPanel x:Name="uxBookingSearchPanel">
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <StackPanel x:Name="uxSearchCriteria">
            <Grid>
            ....
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Height="56">
        ....
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <g4:ProductListControl x:Name="productListControl" />
</DockPanel>
```

**Controls.ProductListControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Controls.ProductListControl">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="uxProducts"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              Margin="0,5,0,0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ProductListControl.ProductName.TextBlock.Text}"
                                Width="150"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ProductListControl.ProductBarcode.TextBlock.Text}"
                                Width="150"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=Barcode}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="DataGridColumnQuantity"
                                    Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ProductListControl.ProductQuantity.TextBlock.Text}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <g4:IntSlider x:Name="uxQuantity" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: uxQuantity is inside DataTemplate for a grid cell. That means there can be many cells and in each cell there will be control named uxQuantity. So for that reason you cannot access uxQuantity from outside DataTemplate iself.

Comment: @Evk, is it possible if I know the given row/column number?

Comment: For what do you need `uxQuantity`? To get it you can traverse visual tree down from `DataGridItem` (not sure, never worked with `DataGrid` yet). In MVVM you would have dedicated item type assigned to `DataGrid.ItemsSource` which will contain all needed for the view properties, which you then use (bind) in datatemplate.

Answer (score 1):

uxQuantity control is inside DataTemplate for a grid cell. That means there can be many cells and in each cell there will be control named uxQuantity. So for that reason you cannot access uxQuantity from outside DataTemplate iself.

Even if you know row and column, I doubt you can access that - but that does not matter, because you should not access your controls in datatemplates anyway. Better think in the other direction - bind properties of your IntSlider you need access to to properties in your data model and access those properties from code.